# database access using jersey RESTful API

Tags: java, mysql, jax-rs

How to access database using jersey RESTful JAX-RS api??
This is hello.java my jersey server side

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/hello")  
public class Hello 
{
    // This method is called if HTML and XML is not requested  
      @GET  
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)  
      public String sayPlainTextHello() 
      {  
          return "Hello Jersey Plain";  
      }  
      // This method is called if XML is requested  
      @GET  
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
      public String sayXMLHello() 
      {  
          return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";  
      }  

      // This method is called if HTML is requested  
      @GET  
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)  
      public String sayHtmlHello() 
      {  
          return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"  
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey HTML" + "</h1></body>" + "</html> ";  
      }  

}
```

Now I wan my server side code to return contact detatils(xml format) stored in my database when my client calls this url in.

Comment: Not sure why you are asking this question? Haven't you accessed database earlier?

Comment: I want to use this service in my android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is a acces layer if you look at the [specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311). So to acces a database you should probebely need to use [JPA](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) implmentation like Hibernate, for that you need a implementation depending on the vendor of your database.

Answer (score 2):

Jersey provides functionally for rest services only. To access a database you need to either use a jdbc or as another abstraction jpa. Have a look at hibernate for jpa.